# Strange error when using application Tomcat

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat

I start the tomcat and when the first page is loaded the error shows:

```
Jan 05, 2014 9:15:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
Grave: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/odontonew] threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.setBufferSize(ResponseFacade.java:252)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.setResponseBufferSize(ExternalContextImpl.java:799)
```

The error occur in this Filer

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        //
        if (((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURI().contains(
                "security/form_login.xhtml")) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        UsuarioMBImpl usuarioMB = (UsuarioMBImpl) ((HttpServletRequest) request)
                .getSession().getAttribute("usuarioMB");

        if (usuarioMB == null || !usuarioMB.isLoggedIn()) {
            String contextPath = ((HttpServletRequest) request)
                    .getContextPath();
            ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect(contextPath
                    + "/security/form_login.xhtml");
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

If i comment everything and let only "chain.doFilter.." everything works fine.

Comment: can you paste more of your logs? There will be a detailed message for the excpetion as well

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `return` statement after the call to `sendRedirect()`:

```
    if (usuarioMB == null || !usuarioMB.isLoggedIn()) {
        String contextPath = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getContextPath();
        ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect(contextPath
                + "/security/form_login.xhtml");
        return;
    }
```